# How can i connectScala.js with mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, scala.js

How can I connect the Scala.js controller method by using mySQL database?

This is what I have so far:

```scala
case class data(user_d: String, udid: String, image: String)

object mysqlDAO {
  def findById(udid: Long): Option[data] = {
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/umo", "root", "")

    try {
      val statement = connection.prepareStatement("""select * from messages where udid = ?""")
      statement.setLong(1, udid)
      val rs = statement.executeQuery()
      if (rs.next())
        Option(new data(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)))
      else
        Option.empty
    } finally {
      connection.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
first of all you can create the case class in Model package then u can create object and serialize the your case class Data 


    ----------


    case class Data(user_id: String, id: String, image: String)

    object Data {
    /*   this one is the serialization of the data*/
      implicit val DataWrites = new Writes[Data] {
        def writes(json_write: Data): JsValue = {
          Json.obj(
            "user_id" -> json_write.user_id,
            "id" -> json_write.id,
            "image" -> json_write.image

          )
        }
      }
      val simple = {
        get[String]("user.user_id") ~
          get[String]("user.id") ~
          get[String]("user.image") map {
            case user_id ~ id ~ image =>
              Data(user_id, id, image)
          }
      }
      /*to get the data */
      def find(udid: String): Option[Data] = {
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
          SQL(ConstantSQL.GET_DETAILS).on('uid -> id).as(Data.simple.singleOpt)
        }
      }

    }


    ----------
    //query for to get the data based on the uid
     val GET_DETAILS = """select * from user_image where uid = ?"""

    then u can create your own controller method


    ----------


    var uDetails = Data.find(uid)


    ----------
    use the above line to get the data in your class
```